# FirebaseUser in Object on FirebaseDatabse does not load correctly Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm currently developing an app on android studio, but I'm stuck. Here is my problem : I've created a new Class Utilisateur (user in french)

```
public class Utilisateur {
private String nom;
private String societe;
private String telephone;
private FirebaseUser user;

public Utilisateur( String nom, String societe, String telephone, FirebaseUser user){
    this.nom = nom;
    this.societe = societe;
    this.telephone = telephone;
    this.user = user;
}

public Utilisateur(){

}
```

I'm using the FirebaseUser provide by FirebaseAuth to regognize on my app which user will be connect to the Utilisateur account.
Here is my problem, when I load all Utilisateur account from my Firebase database, it's works well and all parameters will be present (nom, societe, telephone, user). The only problem is the user is always null even if it's not in my database (FirebaseUser is a no null object).

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot datasnapshotUser : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Utilisateur utilisateur = datasnapshotUser.getValue(Utilisateur.class);
                listUtilisateur.add(utilisateur);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

[On the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7PsG.png)

[image]

[On my FirebaseDatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqdGo.png)

[image]

The fact that FirebaseUser is not save on the parameter's name user on my FirebaseDatabase is quite problemetic. My line test to save an Utilisateur data was 
`Utilisateur newUtilisateur = new Utilisateur("A completer","A completer","A completer",mAuth.getCurrentUser());`

So my question is : Is it really impossible to save a FirebaseUser on a predefine parameter ? Or is it simply a mistake.

Thanks for eventual answers.

Comment: Provide expanded structure of firebaseUser

Comment: What is the value of the `myRef`? Please responde with @AlexMamo